# Как правильно спроектировать абстрактный DAO интерфейс и стоит ли вообще это делать?

Tags: java, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, dao

Всякий раз сталкиваясь с написанием очередного DAO, я споткаюсь об одну и ту же проблему - проектирование максимально абстрактного интерфейса DAO, удовлетворяющего нуждам Service Layer. Примерно так выглядит обычный DAO/Repository во всех Hello World.

```
interface DAO {

    Entity get(Long id);
    List<Entity> getAll();
    void save(Entity e);
    void update(Entity e);
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

К сожалению, таких идеальных маленьких сущностей немного, и во всех приложениях, что я писал, требовалось прикрутить более-менее сложный поиск. Со всеми этими JOIN, GROUP BY, HAVING и прочим SQL, ну вы и так знаете. И вот в этом конкретном месте всегда оказывается, что выразить с помощью ООП критерии поиска, которые так просто и очевидно ложатся на SQL, та еще задачка.

Обычно в таких случаях DAO начинает обрастать кучей методов, которые напрямую удовлетворяют нуждам сервиса. Часто до такой степени, что совпадают сигнатуры методов, и единственное что делает сервис, это оборачивает метод DAO в транзакцию.

```
interface DAO {

    // немного утрируем, но для примера сойдет
    List<Entity> findByUsernameAndStatusAndDate(String userName, Status status, Date lastLogged);
    Long countByUsernameAndStatusAndDate(String userName, Status status, Date lastLogged);

    //.. еще 100500 таких же методов
}
```

Как-то раз меня это порядком достало, и я написал примерно следующее:

```
interface DAO {

    List<Entity> find(String queryName, Param[]... params);
    Long count(String queryName, Param[]... params);
}

class Param<V> {

    String name;
    V value;
}
```

Второй способ предлагает более гибкий интерфейс, но при этом мы имеем leaky abstraction, поскольку детали реализация DAO "протекли" в сервис.

За последнее время я перелопатил просто кучу материала, пытаясь найти какой-то универсальный принцип написания "search API", который можно применить к DAO. Нашел несколько способов:

1. Query By Example - в качестве параметров поиска передается объект того же класса, который мы ищем. Подходит только для простых случаев.
2. JPA Criteria API - можно передать условия поиска в виде списка предикатов. Очень выразительный API, который, к сожалению, реализован только для JPA. Писать аналог для JDBC долго и муторно.
3. Так назывемый Specification - нигде толком не описан, напоминает вырожденный Criteria API. Довольно многословный, и с треском ломается при попытке описать что-то более-менее сложное.

**Вопросы:**

Явлется ли протекающий в сервис DAO таким уж "code smell"? Стоит ли вообще стремиться реализовать поиск с помощью abstract/generic DAO или лучше и дальше пачками клепать специфичные методы под каждый новый use case и не выпендриваться?

Comment: Я не сильно искушён  в написании dao, но сколько я понимаю DAO слой должен быть максимально прост и методы в нём соответственно просты. Если он получается сложным, то что то не так с дизайном наверное или подходом. Вопрос интересный.

Comment: @diofloyk DAO будет простым, только если у вас простые задачи. Как только вы начинаете использовать возможности DBMS для построения сложных запросов, DAO тоже пропорционально усложняется. Если к вам подходит DBA и говорит, сделай вот тут выборку с такими критериями, половина из которых динамические, никакой дизайн вам не поможет. Только хорошо продуманный (либо предельно простой) API для построения условий выборки. Думаю, в динамических языках с этим намного проще, поскольку в них есть нормальная реализация словарей и не надо париться с типами. Ну, и JDBC, конечно, то еще чудище.

Comment: будем ждать экспертов )

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно создаю абстрактный обобщенный DAO класс, в котором описаны общие CRUD операции и что-то чуть более, как то поиск по ids, который можно незатрано и понятно описать на генериках. Остальное специфичное уходит уже в конкретную реализацию db/jpa сервиса. По ходу проекта с пониманием требований обычно выявляются общие места, которые можно/нужно вынести в родительский класс.
Я думаю, автор гонится за прекрасным. DAO не таблетка от всех бед.

Answer (score 0):

В одной из задач я использовал объект поиска, это отдельный класс, который описывает все возможное поля поиска.

Это была учебная задача с книгами и надо было создать поиск по всем полям (автор, название, издательство, дата выпуска точная или промежуток).

На ваш суд предложу такое решение.

```
interface Template{

    // метод вернет готовую строку с параметрами
    // param1 = param and param2 = param2...
    String getfindString();
}
```

И у вас есть сущность книги:

```
class Book{
     String author;
     String title;
     Date date;
}
```

Остается создать сущность для поиска:

```
class BookFindTemplate implements Template{
     String author;
     String title;
     Date afterDate;
     Date beforeDate;

     String getfindString(){
          String Builder query = new StringBuilder();
          query.append(формируем условие запроса, которое идет после where);
          //в моем исполнении логика была очень страшная.
          return query.toString();
     }
}
```

Тогда в ДАО у вас остаются методы поиска, в которые вы передаете образец поиска, он уже сообщит что искать и как искать, вам остается указать в какой таблице это искать.

Вопрос где держать эти образцы, в дао или в модели. Т.к. там формируется часть sql запроса, думаю стоит поближе к ДАО.

Comment: Ну во-первых, у вас там SQL Injection, потому что я не вижу логики через которую вы сообщите PreparedStatement, какие параметры реально были использованы. И если вы ее добавите, то ваш пример станет в несколько раз страшнее. А если вы еще и захотите использовать IN(..), то совсем жутким :) Во-вторых, ваша реализация тоже протекла, потому что сервис в таком случае должен будет знать с DAO какой DBMS он работает, чтобы создать объект Template соот. класса, либо иногда в DAO придется создавать свою обертку над ним.

Comment: По большому счету, все что вы сделали, это вынесли параметры метода в отдельный класс, т.е. упростили сигнатуру. При этом не получили никакого реального профита от самой идеи, и даже усложнили себе жизнь, размазав логику построения запроса, потому что метод `getfindString` можно спокойно вынести в DAO, где его функции никак не изменятся, но вам будет намного проще использовать какой-нибудь SQL Builder и рефакторить код в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если быть откровенным, то DAO не очень подходит для таких задач. Данный паттерн предназначен только для CRUD методов, в то время как Repository, для этого и предназначен, он имеет специфические запросы которые для DAO не подойдут. Так что с понятием Repository и для чего он нужен вроде как разобрали.

По абстракции. Я же все таки использовал бы максимально простой подход и более гибкий подход. Если сигнатуры совпадают, ничего страшного. Если приложение будет большим, то ты потом будешь скучать по таким "совпадениям". Следует помнить что сервис для логики, а репозиторий для работы с БД, и если ты через бд получаешь все что нужно, то это хорошо.